# How do I find the highest value and swap it with the end value in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

This is my python code so far and the result I'm getting at the end is [5, 2, 3, 12, 1, 12].

```
array = [5,2,3,12,1,6]
temp = ''
lastvalue = 5
highestvalue = array[0]

i=0



while i<5:

    if array[i]>highestvalue:
        highestvalue = array[i]


    i+=1

print(highestvalue)
temp = array[5]
array[5] = highestvalue
highestvalue = temp



print(array)
```

I'm looking for the result [5,2,3,6,1,12]
.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**temp** is a separate variable, not an array element.  Instead, identify the position needed, and swap with that.  I assume that you're doing it "the hard way" (without **min** and **max** methods) for homework?

```
array = [5,2,3,12,1,6]
highest_pos = 0
i=0

for i in range(len(array)):
    if array[i] > array[highest_pos]:
        highest_pos = i
    i+=1

print(array[highest_pos])
temp = array[-1]
array[-1] = array[highest_pos]
array[highest_pos] = temp

print(array)
```

Note also that I've changed your **5** references to use either the list length or the final element, -1.  Negative numbers index a list from the opposite (right) end.

Comment: Thank you but what does array[-1] mean?

Comment: @HarrisonCroaker It gets the last element of the list

Comment: @HarrisonCroaker: see the last sentence in my answer.  Also, I removed two initialization statements: **highestvalue** is no longer used, and **temp** is initialized just below the first **print** statement.

Comment: @Keatinge ahh yess i see

Answer (score 1):

Why not just get the indexes and swap the values

```
array = [5,2,3,12,1,6]

maxI = array.index(max(array))
minI = array.index(min(array))

array[maxI], array[minI] = array[minI], array[maxI]
```

Answer (score 0):

I made two modifications with your code: (1) You need to store the index of the highest value in the array in your for loop (2) You need to change your method of swapping the last and highest value in the array at the last section of your code.

```
array = [5,2,3,12,1,6]
temp = ''
lastvalue = 5
highestvalue = array[0]

i=0



while i<5:

    if array[i]>highestvalue:
        highestvalue = array[i]
        index = i # store the index of the highest value


    i+=1

print(highestvalue)
temp = array[5]
array[5] = highestvalue
array[index] = temp # correct way to swap the highest value to the end value of your array



print(array)
```